# Is there any way to measure a photon and allowing it to continue on its path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, double-slit-experiment, quantum-measurements

In the context of the double slit experiment and variants thereof, although it doesn't have to be this context, my question is more generic:

Is there any way to measure the position or momentum of a photon?

From what I understand, any instrument that uses the photoelectric effect will basically convert the photon to an electron. It is unclear to me what principle, if any, could be used to measure the photon (even if only partially) without also destroying it.

Is there such a way to measure a photon? I understand that any measurement will alter the state of the photon due to the uncertainty principle. However, I'm curious if by allowing some modifications to occur, it is still possible to in part measure the photon whilst still allowing it to continue down its (somewhat modified perhaps) path.

Comment: For a bounded photon, it was done in the work of Serge Haroche.

Comment: Relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Weak_measurement

Comment: No.  Most/all photon position measurements are done using absorption like a CCD (camera) or your eye or film.  This is not the photo electric effect ... which is a special case. Upon absorption the photon is gone.

Comment: Weak measurement is interesting .... but requires many photons.

Comment: You can measure the polarization of a photon without much affecting it.  That will work for some percentage of photons depending on whether you use a polarizer (which will absorb photons that don't pass) or a polarizing beam splitter (which will alter the path of some photons, but not all).  You can do something somewhat similar with a filter tuned to a specific wavelength.

Note: As @PhysicsDave says, upon absorption the photon is gone.  It does not "convert" to an electron.

Comment: Compton scattering.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, edges can cause polarisation of photons. The photons do not come close enough to the surface electrons of the edge to be absorbed. However, the photons are still in the sphere of influence of the electrons and interact in such a way that they are polarised behind narrow slits - no matter what orientation their electric/magnetic field component had before. This happens without energy transfer, otherwise it would have already been observed that the EM radiation is red-shifted behind polarisation gratings.

**TL;DR**
Since the radiation is polarised, one could come up with the idea that the grid surface is also polarised according to action - counteraction. Which would be our chance to measure the flyby of photons. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

This is due to the fact that although the photons have aligned electric and magnetic field components after the lattice, the phases of the oscillations for two photons can be opposite. For example, if the direction of the electric field of one photon points to the right at a given time, this direction may point to the left for the photon nearby. In other words, behind the grating, on average, the electric fields of the photons point to the "right" and half to the "left".

And now it becomes interesting. The polarization of an EM radiation at a grating cannot be a spooky phenomenon. There is always a cause. I dare to conclude that the change of the polarization direction of the "right" photons is caused by the change of the polarization direction of the "left" photons. The surface electrons of the edges are in the role of the catalyst, they influence the polarization direction, but they have no energy change. And with that, we have no chance to measure anything.

Whereby one should never give up. If the application of an electric field to the grating should change the deflection of the polarized EM radiation behind the grating - which has never been observed, but probably has never been investigated - the resistance change on applying a voltage to the grating could be different for the case of interaction with EM radiation and a polarization grating at rest.
**TL;DR**